# Is it possible to block outgoing emails to a particular address?

Tags: gmail

Say if I wish not to send an email to an address, even by mistake, because I want to maintain no contact between the two emails, is it possible to set up some kind of outgoing filter to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup filters on outgoing mail to add labels, but **at present there is no way to BLOCK outgoing mail to a specific address.**

*If you are using Google Apps for Business, you can enable [Postini](http://www.google.com/postini/) which supports [whitelist and blacklists](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60752)*

Comment: u mean to say its available in Google Apps for Business?

Comment: @thale yes, using postini you can whitelist or blacklist email addresses & IP's - see updated question